# How can I get the coordinates of a Label inside a view?

Tags: ios, swift, label

What I am trying to do is to get the position of my label (timerLabel) in order to pass those coordinates to UIBezierPath (so that the center of the shape and the center of the label coincide).
Here's my code so far, inside the viewDidLoad method, using Xcode 13.2.1:

```
//        getting the center of the label
        let center = CGPoint.init(x: timerLabel.frame.midX , y: timerLabel.frame.midY)
//        drawing the shape
        let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineWidth = 10
        trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
```

and this is what I have when I run my app:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjKY5.png)

What I don't understand is why I get (0,0) as coordinates even though I access the label's property (timerLabel.frame.midX).

Comment: try to put this code in viewDidAppear and see it works?

Comment: Where are you calling this code from ?

Comment: I'm calling it inside the viewDidLoad method

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` your views are not yet laid out. Try to find out view frames in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or later.

Comment: @AndreaOlmo - as other commenters suggested, maybe add it in a place like `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` which will be called after the as your UI frames are set only at this point and it will be before the screen is seen. However, have a flag to check if you have created this or not so you do it only once as calls like  `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will be called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates of your label may vary depending on current layout. You need to track all changes and reposition your circle when changes occur. In view controller that uses constraints you would override

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    // recreate your circle here
}
```

this alone does not explain why your circle is so far out. First of all, looking at your image you do not get `(0, 0)` but some other value which may be relative position of your label within the blue bubble. The `frame` is always relative to its superview so you need to convert that into your own coordinate system:

```
let targetView = self.view!
let sourceView = timerLabel!
    
let centerOfSourceViewInTargetView: CGPoint = targetView.convert(CGPoint(x: sourceView.bounds.midX, y: sourceView.bounds.midY), to: targetView)
// Use centerOfSourceViewInTargetView as center
```

but I suggest using neither of the two. If you are using constraints (which you should) then rather create more views than adding layers to your existing views.

For instance you could try something like this:

```
@IBDesignable class CircleView: UIView {
    
    @IBInspectable var lineWidth: CGFloat = 10 { didSet { refresh() } }
    @IBInspectable var strokeColor: UIColor = .lightGray { didSet { refresh() } }
    
    override var frame: CGRect { didSet { refresh() } }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        refresh()
    }
 
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        let fillRadius: CGFloat = min(bounds.width, bounds.height)*0.5
        let strokeRadius: CGFloat = fillRadius - lineWidth*0.5
        
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: .init(x: bounds.midX-strokeRadius, y: bounds.midY-strokeRadius, width: strokeRadius*2.0, height: strokeRadius*2.0))
        path.lineWidth = lineWidth
        strokeColor.setStroke()
        UIColor.clear.setFill() // Probably not needed
        path.stroke()
    }

    private func refresh() {
        setNeedsDisplay() // This is to force redraw
    }
    
}
```

this view should draw your circle within itself by overriding draw rect method. You can easily use it in your storyboard (first time it might not draw in storyboard because Xcode. Simply close your project and reopen it and you should see the circle even in storyboard).
Also in storyboard you can directly modify both line width and stroke color which is very convenient.

About the code:

- Using `@IBDesignable` to see drawing in storyboard
- Using `@IBInspectable` to be able to set values in storyboard
- Refreshing on any value change to force redraw (sometimes needed)
- When frame changes forcing a redraw (Needed when setting frame from code)
- A method `layoutSubviews` is called when resized from constraints. Again redrawing.
- Path is computed so that it fits within the size of view.

Comment: Thank you, especially for the second part of your answer, I didn't know the existence of IBDesignable and IBInspectable. I tried using it but I ended up preferring the first solution since it was easier to read (I'm new at programming). Sadly, even thought I wrote targetView, sourceView and centerOfSourceViewInTargetView inside viewDidLayoutSubviews() the result is similar to the picture attached to the question. The circle and its animation is also declared inside viewDidLayoutSubviews().